# rakudo: command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raku, rakudo

I have installed rakudo using `sudo apt install rakudo` which completes successfully, but when I try to run it I get an error:

```
sashoalm@HP:~$ rakudo --version
rakudo: command not found
```

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. Is rakudo installed but not in my `PATH`?

Comment: The standard package installs in `/usr/bin/rakudo` so that would be extremely unusual. You don't show your `PATH` so we can't verify. You can look in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/rakudo.list` to see exactly what was installed and where. Did you configure unusual software sources? What does `apt-cache info rakudo` reveal? This does not look like a programming question really anyway.

Comment: I suppose there could be a problem with your shell, too. Try `hash -r rakudo` if you are using Bash.

Comment: I checked the deb file - I guess my OS is old and it installed it in /usr/bin but as perl6 instead of rakudo - even though the package itself was named rakudo.

Comment: [Indeed.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/rakudo/filelist) Sorry, I only checked on a newer Ubuntu.

Comment: You also might want to check out https://nxadm.github.io/rakudo-pkg/ which has up-to-date packages for a *lot* of Linuxes!

Comment: What happens with `raku --version` ? Or `perl6 --version` ? Just typing `raku` or `perl6` at the command prompt should open the REPL for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded and inspected the deb file, and it was installed as `/usr/bin/perl6` - even though the package itself was named rakudo. I guess this is because my OS is old.

Comment: It's likely that it's also available as `raku`, as an alias. You might want to use [rakubrew](https://rakubrew.org) to install whatever version you want in userspace.

Comment: Hi @sashoalm. If you are able to accept your answer, please do that to tidy up. Thanks.